# Is it possible to query a specific DSN server for a web page?

Tags: web, dns, routes, hosting

I have the IP address of the DNS server from the WebHost. Since we do not own the Domain Name (Its the client's DN) I would like to query the WebHost DNS directly to see if it works before asking the client to point his DN to the WebHost DNS.

Am I missing something here? I'm kinda confused when it comes to configures online services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Windows Command Prompt:

```
nslookup
server x.x.x.x (put the WebHost DNS IP address there)
www.yourdomain.com  (type the name of the domain you want resolved)
quit
```

Comment: Mmm that seems to be what i'm looking for, however, when I query for the web site, it says connection timed out. Even for the sites known to work.

Comment: You can try:

    tracert x.x.x.x (put your web site address there)

and see what you get back.

The timeout might suggest that you are getting to the site, but the site is taking too long to process your request.